# Is Windows Mobile on topic?

Tags: discussion

[Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) started with Windows CE in 1990.  Some could argue that many versions of Windows Mobile are dead and obsolete. On the other hand, it has evolved and improved and the latest version of the operating system, Windows Mobile 6.5, has been updated as recently as 2012.

Is Windows Mobile on topic for this site or should we focus on Windows Phone 7 and up?

Comment: Another question [here](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/595/sniff-com-port-in-windows-mobile-device)

Comment: We need to add this to the FAQ or we will keep getting these questions.

Comment: I think the majority want too.

Comment: Kalamane, and @VitorCanova, we need to refine our FAQ, not just add one item at a  time. see http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-should-our-faq-contain

Comment: @Joe We can't edit FAQ correclty? So we need to create a new FAQ and post here to some Moderator change?

Comment: right, we are unable to edit the FAQ. using the thread I linked to, we can refine and build what we want our FAQ to say. Once critical mass has hit I'm, sure someone will edit it for us

Comment: FYI: the link to the question referenced above is now dead

Answer (score 11):

This is a tough one for me. Although Windows Mobile is in the family, it has been discontinued. I am worried that would end up getting a decent amount of unanswered questions because of the lack of expertise.

My vote is **no**, but I wouldn't be hurt is you thought otherwise.

Comment: +1 for discontinuity, while it might be somewhat acceptable now it could be deprecated in a few years.

Answer (score 6):

My vote would also be NO.

you have to set a line somewhere. are other windows CE based operating systems also on topic here then? Those industrial CE devices?

I'd say since Windows mobile is discontinued (and from Windows Phone 8 it's not even family anymore since wp8 is based on the win8 kernel) let's not discuss Windows Mobile topics

Answer (score 6):

My vote is NO. This would make the discussions complicated and as Joe said a lot of questions might remain unanswered because of the OS being almost dead.
My company still uses it though.. but that's another story.

Answer (score 3):

In short, I'd say **YES**, We should *allow* questions on Windows Mobile.

The [FAQ](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq) currently lists it as on topic, Area 51 says [Q&A site for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Mobile and Windows Phone 7.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/).

Given there is no other place where questions are accepted on Windows Mobile devices (they started getting closed on SuperUser when Android & Apple got their own sites), I'd say that there is no harm in letting them get answered here -- some are still in active service, so should we turn these people away? I'd rather be more inclusive about and let time naturally filter off questions as they fall in market share.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this site when it was a proposal for Windows Mobile.
I have a Windows Mobile 5.0 "smartphone" in my family and I believe that Windows Phone is a continuation of the Windows Mobile line of devices.

It's not a coincidence that Windows Phone started at version 7 when the last version of Windows Mobile was 6.5.

Comment: From what I understand there is really very little in common between them from a user's perspective, and intentionally so, because Microsoft realized WinMo wasn't going anywhere.  I also doubt that the numbering was based on continuing from the old; Microsoft tends to number things whatever suits them, and Windows 7 was their desktop OS when WP7 was released, which matches nicely.

Comment: The only continuation Microsoft have in terms of Windows Mobile and Windows Phone is the number. Is a complete refresh in the OS and probably should be better an exclusive site for Windows Mobile instead.

Comment: I think an exclusive site for Windows Mobile would have limited opportunities for growth because it's discontinued. Keeping it on topic here, I believe, is the best way for it to exist as a stack exchange site.

Comment: if it is discontinued why should it remain on topic here? How much interest is there in Windows Mobile? It doesn't seem like there is much. I fear it would become noise.