# Can Windows Mobile be made off topic in the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, scope

The state of [this discussion](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-windows-mobile-on-topic) is that Windows Mobile **should be** off topic. Can we have the FAQ updated to say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), one of the important things that a beta community should do is work on their [faq](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq).

So, yes - the faq can be edited.  But rather than just sticking a single item there, it would be beneficial for this community to work on tailor the faq to make it your own.

---

> #### 2. What should our FAQ contain?
>
> Much of the FAQ will be somewhat boilerplate: "be nice," "how to create an account," "how to ask questions" -- it's all pretty static. Even the sections about "what kind of questions should I (not) ask here?" comes primarily from  [the Definition phase of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).
>
> But the questions you want to discuss in meta are those issues specific to your site that need to be mentioned in the FAQ.
>
> Take the [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) as an example:
>
> > Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

It took us almost a year to figure out the list of "we want these sort of questions" and "we don't want these sort of questions" on Super User. Area 51 gave you a head start but you should also be working out other FAQ-related issues *specific to your topic and your community*.

Comment: What have you found the best format for this question is? Should we make a single Community Wiki question that can be edited to add official decisions, and it will be merged into the FAQ when it has critical mass? Should each answer be a proposal, and the comments be the discussion?

Comment: @Joe: Because nobody else seems to be jumping on the Top 7 questions, I'll be posting some of them. As for the format it doesn't really matter as we're still very very early, the thing is that we want discussion going on. In a few days we can create another meta question for a draft FAQ, then near the end of the public beta we can work towards a more real FAQ (which can still be adjusted later). The amount of Windows Mobile question is very low, so it doesn't pose a big issue, but I kind of agree that we have to work to get it out of the FAQ around the start of public beta. No need to worry...

Comment: @Joe: As you are already fitting in a on-topic / off-topic style, I'll minimize my paragraph about the answer format so they are more likely to take over your style. :)

Answer (score 0):

It also needs to be removed from the [about](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/about) page and the welcome text on the main page:

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for
>   enthusiasts and power users of Windows Mobile and Windows Phone 7.
>   It's 100% free, no registration required.