# Tag Input Suggests Using Off Topic Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems that Windows Mobile has been declared [off](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-windows-mobile-on-topic) [topic](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/can-windows-mobile-be-made-off-topic-in-the-faq), however the example text in the tag input suggests using [windows-mobile-2003](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-mobile-2003) as a tag. Can we change it so that an off-topic tag isn't used as an example?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the tags from the questions such that it doesn't show up anymore in the examples, which are taken from tags that are often used. The dead tags will soon automatically get removed from the system.

Unless the "often used tags" system is bogus, I would say this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Great, seems like it doesn't show up anymore.